# Stored procedure expects parameter 'Incorrect syntax near ':'.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [PROC_SET_BRN_RPT_STSTC]  
    @I_RPT_I varchar(max),
    @I_MSTR_TBL varchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @VD_PSTG_D datetime2(0),
        @V_SQL varchar(4000),
        @BMG_RPT_I varchar(5) = ISNULL(@I_RPT_I, '') + 'M',
        @MAM_RPT_I varchar(5) = ISNULL(@I_RPT_I, '') + 'P';

    /*vd_pstg_d   :=  GET_DATE ('TDTD');*/
    SELECT @VD_PSTG_D = max(TIME_DIMN.DATE_D)
    FROM TIME_DIMN
    WHERE TIME_DIMN.TME_DIMN_I IN ( 'TDTD', 'TDSH' );

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500); 
    SET @SQLString = 'Delete From RPT_STSTC Where TXN_PSTG_D = :1 and Rpt_i = :2';
    Execute sp_executesql @SQLString, @vd_pstg_d, @I_Rpt_I;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

When I try to execute the stored procedure, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Do you know what would be the issue?

Comment: SQL Server uses named parameters, so you need `Where TXN_PSTG_D = @vd_pstg_d and Rpt_i = @I_Rpt_I`. Unclear why you need dynamic SQL, this can be done as a normal `DELETE`

Comment: FYI procedures do not need to be wrapped in BEGIN..END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment on your question, there is no need for dynamic SQL in this stored procedure. You could just rewrite it:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [PROC_SET_BRN_RPT_STSTC]  
    @I_RPT_I varchar(max),
    @I_MSTR_TBL varchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @VD_PSTG_D datetime2(0),
        @V_SQL varchar(4000),
        @BMG_RPT_I varchar(5) = ISNULL(@I_RPT_I, '') + 'M',
        @MAM_RPT_I varchar(5) = ISNULL(@I_RPT_I, '') + 'P';

    /*vd_pstg_d   :=  GET_DATE ('TDTD');*/
    SELECT @VD_PSTG_D = max(TIME_DIMN.DATE_D)
    FROM TIME_DIMN
    WHERE TIME_DIMN.TME_DIMN_I IN ( 'TDTD', 'TDSH' );

    DELETE FROM RPT_STSTC 
    WHERE TXN_PSTG_D = @vd_pstg_d AND Rpt_i = @I_Rpt_I;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Only use `sp_executesql` if you absolutely need to use it - here you do not need it.

Just to answer your question, here is what you could have done (but it is not advised in this simple scenario):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [PROC_SET_BRN_RPT_STSTC]  
    @I_RPT_I varchar(max),
    @I_MSTR_TBL varchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @VD_PSTG_D datetime2(0),
        @V_SQL varchar(4000),
        @BMG_RPT_I varchar(5) = ISNULL(@I_RPT_I, '') + 'M',
        @MAM_RPT_I varchar(5) = ISNULL(@I_RPT_I, '') + 'P';

    /*vd_pstg_d   :=  GET_DATE ('TDTD');*/
    SELECT @VD_PSTG_D = max(TIME_DIMN.DATE_D)
    FROM TIME_DIMN
    WHERE TIME_DIMN.TME_DIMN_I IN ( 'TDTD', 'TDSH' );

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500); 
    SET @SQLString = CONCAT('Delete From RPT_STSTC Where TXN_PSTG_D =''', @VD_PSTG_D, ''' AND Rpt_i=''', @I_RPT_I, '''');
    Execute sp_executesql @SQLString, @vd_pstg_d, @I_Rpt_I;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thank you Bjorg. What is the need or `DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);` in the first SQL?

Comment: @beckham my fault, I forgot to delete it... I will correct

Answer (score 0):

The `:1` and `:2` are the problem.

You want to fill variables in there, but that is the wrong way. You need to use the variables there and can't use placeholders like in other languages.

```
SET @SQLString = 'Delete From RPT_STSTC Where TXN_PSTG_D =  @vd_pstg_d and Rpt_i = @I_Rpt_I';
```

The syntax with `:1` and `:2` does not exist in T-SQL.